# LightGBM Classifier faster on CPU than on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, lightgbm

I've followed instructions in [official documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html) of LightGBM. I followed each step and when I tried to make the speed test on both GPU and CPU I noticed that **CPU computation is faster than GPU**. However, computer recognizes the GPU and complains about nothing. **Any clue about why is this happening?** According to the tutorial, GPU should be at least three times faster.

I tried with my own dataset and Sklearng API (LightGBMClassifier) and it happens the same.
I'm working on a Debian 11, with a Nvidia GPU Tesla T4. I installed the drivers 470.182 and `nvidia-smi` works properly. It's a Google Cloud Virtual Machine.

Already check similar questions (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742614/lightgbm-benchmark-shows-no-speedup-on-rtx-2080-gpu-over-cpu)), but no answers found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large is your dataset, its dinension size, and what type of model are you training?

Comment: These are many reasons why his could happen that's why I ask.

Comment: @JesseSealand It's a classifier. The same exact model and dataset than used in official GPU tutorial: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html